# WPF window pre-loading

Tags: c#, wpf, window

When switching between windows in my full screen WPF app, if it is the first time the screen has been shown, The monitor will go black momentarily before the windows is displayed. This only happens the first time the window is shown. Is there a way to pre-load each window so this does not happen?

This is what I've tried:

```
myWindow.Show();
myWindow.Hide();
```

but there is a visible flicker.

Then I tried:

```
myWindow.Height = 0;
myWindow.Width = 0;
myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
myWindow.Show();
myWindow.Hide();
myWindow.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
myWindow.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

No flicker, but when I then shown the window it showed itself in a weird state for a split second then updated to display properly.

Comment: I just want to add that its not only problem of full screen apps. I have the same problem when open new window that contains a lot of visuals. Problem is in creating thousands different wrappers e.g. for items in items controls, first-time layout building and rendering. The same issue is possible when switching to tab containing lots of controls for first time. So if anybody knows how to pre-load control, it would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this person asked a clearer question.

[How can I avoid flicker in a WPF fullscreen app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364340/how-can-i-avoid-flicker-in-a-wpf-fullscreen-app)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In the end I created a splash screen and loaded the controls up behind the splash screen in a seperate thread. This stopped the flashing, but made the initail app load longer.

Comment: how did you do that? be instantiating all the windows in the splash screen without showing them?