# Transparent Splash Screen (WinForms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I created a transparent splash screen in VB.Net 2012; it looks great, except one problem that it appear inside a white box for few seconds before it become transparent. The way I created it is by using *.bmp image with pink color background, then I use the pink as transparent in the form properties. I am not sure why this ugly white box appears. 
Any help/opinion is appreciated.
The issue is with WinForms not WPF;
There is no fancy code required to be posted as all what I've done is selected Form2 as per the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: did you remove the form boarders?

Comment: Of course I removed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified whether your app is WPF or WinForms.

If your app is using WPF this may be related to a known issue:

- [WPF Window with black background flashes white when first shown](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bdb414fe-9abb-408c-8935-486e1795755b/wpf-window-with-black-background-flashes-white-when-first-shown?forum=wpf)

There is a [related Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364863/2012417) with some suggested workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Phillip for the respond, I have WinForm; is there a solution for this? If I understand correctly, the solutions in your links are only for WPF, correct?

Comment: @Abbas1999 the solutions in my links are WPF specific. If your issue is on WinForms, I'd recommend updating your question with that information and ideally a code snippet

Comment: Phillips; I've added more details and an image to make the question more clear as you've suggested. Help appreciated.